# Can't take photos but space available!

Tags: photos, space

My phone says I have 494gb available (I just spent $9.99 for cloud space!) but I'm not able to take any photos!! What do I do?

Comment: Have you checked how much space you have left on your phone?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have run out of space on your phone. While you may have 494GB of space available in iCloud, your phone needs a place to put them before they can be uploaded. Try deleting some existing photos, videos, music, or apps to free up some space on your device.

Comment: is 494GB a typo? Did you mean 49GB? iPhones ship with a Maximum of 128GB. 494GB is almost 4x the amount of space offered on **any** iPhone. Vahsavoc is on the right path. Follow his advice to determine where all your space is going to.

Comment: 500GB corresponds with the $9.99 for iCloud. It's unrelated the the physical memory on the phone.

Comment: No doubt but the question starts with "My phone says I have 494gb available." On the off chance he is not talking about iCloud space I felt it was worth at least mentioning. Hence my usage of the comment form instead of the answer form.

Comment: Indeed, the root of the problem seems to be a misunderstanding of local vs. iCloud storage.

Answer (score 0):

iCloud storage has no correlation to a Device's available space for photos/videos/apps/etc.

To show how much space is free on the device:

```
Settings > General > Usage > Under 'Storage' > Manage Storage
```

From here you can see what is Used vs Available, and you can even see what apps are using the most.